# book mistake php

Tags: php

helo everyone

This is a code from a book i have bought. It gives me the following error.

syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM in

```
preg_match (‚#<!-- START ‚. $tag . ‚ -->(.+?)<!-- END ‚.$tag . ‚ -->#si', $this->content, $tor);
$tor = str_replace (‚<!-- START ‚. $tag . ‚ -->', „", $tor[0]);
$tor = str_replace (‚<!-- END ‚ . $tag . ‚ -->', „", $tor);
```

preg_match is the line. Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: The syntax highligthing should show where the problem is

Comment: I think you just copied the code examples that use typographic quotes instead of the “simple” quotes.

Comment: Gotta love the T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM.  (Means double-colon, for those who were wondering.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just copied the code examples that use [typographic quotation marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark) instead of the “simple” quotation marks `"` and `'`. The code should read:

```
preg_match ('#<!-- START '. $tag . ' -->(.+?)<!-- END '.$tag . ' -->#si', $this->content, $tor);
$tor = str_replace ('<!-- START '. $tag . ' -->', "", $tor[0]);
$tor = str_replace ('<!-- END ' . $tag . ' -->', "", $tor);
```

Comment: thank you so much for answering with the right code! CEO invites you in greece:)

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, strings are delimited by quotes *(either double or simple)*.

Here, you are using some sort of comma as a string delimiter -- which is wrong, and explains the syntax error.

For more informations, and as a reference, you should take a look at the [**Strings section of the PHP manual**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

You should be using something like this, I suppose:

```
preg_match ('#<!-- START '. $tag . ' -->(.+?)<!-- END '.$tag . ' -->#si', $this->content, $tor);
$tor = str_replace ('<!-- START '. $tag . ' -->', '', $tor[0]);
$tor = str_replace ('<!-- END ' . $tag . ' -->', '', $tor);
```